# Auto change position submenu in vertical menu bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, menu, twitter-bootstrap-3, submenu

I see a problem when using vertical menu bootstrap in http://www.bootply.com/122674
Submenu do not auto change position when menu on the right.

Thank!

Answer (score 0):

This right-aligned example works..

http://www.bootply.com/124937

```
.dropdown-submenu{position:relative;}
.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu{top:0;left:-95%;max-width:180px;margin-top:-6px;margin-right:-1px;-webkit-border-radius:6px 6px 6px 6px;-moz-border-radius:6px 6px 6px 6px;border-radius:6px 6px 6px 6px;}
.dropdown-submenu:hover>.dropdown-menu{display:block;}
.dropdown-submenu>a:after{display:block;content:" ";float:left;width:0;height:0;border-color:transparent;border-style:solid;border-width:5px 5px 5px 0;border-right-color:#999;margin-top:5px;margin-right:10px;}
.dropdown-submenu:hover>a:after{border-left-color:#ffffff;}
.dropdown-submenu.pull-left{float:none;}.dropdown-submenu.pull-left>.dropdown-menu{left:-100%;margin-left:10px;-webkit-border-radius:6px 6px 6px 6px;-moz-border-radius:6px 6px 6px 6px;border-radius:6px 6px 6px 6px;}
```

Comment: Thank for answer.
Please view an images http://a.imageshack.us/img850/8020/pub4.png
When menu to right slidebar then position of submenu auto change to left menu.